# INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS : "Insufficient funds to cover the requested amount" in hyperwallet API integration

Tags: node.js, error-handling, payment

I have just integrated Hyperwallet API and it does work well for US.
But it doen't work for other countries for example) Nigeria
It return json error as following.

```
[ { message: 'Insufficient funds to cover the requested amount.',
    code: 'INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS' } ]
```

What should I do? I think I have integrated it correctly.
Anything will be big help.

Comment: The issue could be that as of today 6/9/17, the exchange rate is nearly 315 Naira (Nigerian currency) to 1 Dollar. HyperWallet exchange always converts the currency to dollars so you would need a lot of Naira to cover some lump sum amount.

Comment: Thanks. It was because I set too small amount for funding.